# Dynamic model to predict values based multiple linear regression model in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am running a multiple linear regression model using an available training dataset mtcars.

Now I want to run this model against a test dataset. So I am trying to fetch test dataset manually from user on Shiny UI. User should have an option to select the dependant and independant variables, based on the independant and dependant variable selection, it should give the predicted value of the test dataset

Currently, its is giving an error "could not find function "modelq"

modelq is the linear regression model which I have built(based on mtcars dataset) to predict the values of the test dataset
Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(caret)
library(shiny)
library(curl)

library(shiny)

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My first predictive model"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr(),
      uiOutput("dependent"),
      uiOutput("independents"),
      tags$hr(),
      actionButton("action", "Predict!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("regTab")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  filedata <- reactive({
    infile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(infile)){
      return(NULL)      
    }
    read.csv(infile$datapath)
  })

  output$dependent <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    selectInput("dependent","Select ONE variable as dependent variable from:",items)
  })
  output$independents <- renderUI({
    df <- filedata()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    checkboxGroupInput('independents','Select the regressors', choices = names(df))
  })
  #regression formula
  pred12 <- eventReactive(input$action, {
   modelq <- lm(as.formula(paste(input$dependent," ~ ",paste(input$independents,collapse="+"))),data=mtcars)
  pred1<-predict(modelq(),filedata())
  }
)
  #model
  output$regTab <- renderPrint({
    if(!is.null(input$independents)){
      pred12()
    } else {
      print(data.frame(Warning="Please select Model Parameters."))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: From what you describe I do not get what you want: In machine learning you have a test and a training data set. Now what you do in your app is that you load a test data from files. The problem is that you train your model with the `mtcars` data, meaning that whatever data you load **needs to have the exact same columns as the `mtcars` data**. Otherwise you app will start throwing errors if you choose the wrong columns.

Comment: So I have used mtcars as my training dataset and my test data set is exactly the dummy data set of mtcars, with same columns which mtcars dataset contain. Now I am giving the option to the user to select the dependant and the independant variables from the app and based on the selection first it should build the model with the help of mtcars dataset and then it should predict values (referring to the selection done by the user for dependant and independant variable) for the test data which I have uploaded.

Comment: Just out of experience: Usually you do not build shiny apps for yourself. Hence you try minimising the possibility for errors - why not simply load the dataset, split the loaded dataset into training and test set and then apply the model. Heck! You can event add some controls for the test-training-split. The way you build your app now, seems ineffective to me.

Comment: Could you please tell me if I have to use predict function to predict the values of the test dataset based on the dependant and independant variables selected, how should I modify the the following :pred1<-predict(modelq(),filedata())

Comment: Currently the problem what I think is that the modelq() contains the selected dependant and independant variables , however the filedata() which is the test data contains all the columns thats the reason its giving error

Comment: I am trying to build a forecasting model so that in future if I will get a data of same columns and if one of the columns value is missing then I can upload the file and predict the values of the missing column based on the model which I have build with mtcars dataset. That is the reason I dont want to spilt the file which I will upload into test and train